# insertar datos en base de datos de MySQL con bash

Tags: mysql, bash

Tengo un script que me convierte unos archivos, me crea las carpeta si esta no existe y los mueve a una trayectoria deseada.

```
        echo "estacion: "$st;
        fcha=$year2"-"$month"-"$day;
        echo "fecha: "$fcha;

        echo $archivoF " ==> " $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2"/"$archivoF;
        if [ ! -d $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2 ]; then
          mkdir -p $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2;
        fi
        mv $archivoF $rutabase"datos/obs/"$st"/"$year2
        IFS='.' read -ra tipoO <<< "$archivoF"
        tipoOb=`echo "."${tipoO[1]}"."${tipoO[2]}`

        echo $archivoG " ==> "$rutabase"rinex/nav/"$st"/"$year2"/"$archivoG;
        if [ ! -d $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2 ]; then
        mkdir -p $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2;
        fi
        mv $archivoG $rutabase"datos/nav/"$st"/"$year2
        IFS='.' read -ra tipoN <<< "$archivoG"
        tipoNa=`echo "."${tipoN[1]}`
```

como puedo hacer para insertar datos a mi base de datos a partir de archivos convertirdos.

la tabla que tengo tiene los siguientes campos:

- **nombre** VARCHAR(5)   <--$archivoF,$archivoG
- **tipo** VARCHAR(5)     <--$tipoOb,$tipoNa
- **fecha** DATE          <--$fcha
- **estacion** VARCHAR(5) <--$st

Answer (score 3):

Primero, deberías hacer las inserciones en SQL. Eso lo grabas en un archivo SQL.

Y desde consola lo puedes lanzar así:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -h <HOST> -u <USUARIO> -p<TUPASSWORD> <NOMBRE_DE_TU_BASE_DE_DATOS> < /rutadondeguardartubasededatos/import.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera bastante sencilla así (modifícalo para que coincida exactamente con tus datos):

```
echo "INSERT INTO nombre_de_tabla (nombre,tipo,fecha,estacion) VALUES ('${archivoF},${archivoG}', '${tipoOb},${tipoNa}', '${fcha}', '${st}')" | mysql -u usuario -pcontraseña -h localhost nombre_base_datos
```

Nótese que no hay espacio entre p y la contraseña. El hecho de poner la contraseña en el comando es un fallo de seguridad, pero eso ya sería otra cuestión a resolver a parte.

Answer (score 0):

La consulta SQL se puede hacer con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
mysql -e "CONSULTA SQL" base_de_datos
```

Pero también necesita parámetros de configuración que pueden configurarse añadiendo:

```
mysql -h localhost -uusuario -pclave -e "CONSULTA SQL" base_de_datos
```

Hay que resaltar que no existe separación entre los parámetros `-u` y `-p` y el nombre de usuario o contraseña.

Aunque es más cómodo configurar los datos en un archivo de configuración y guardarlo en `$HOME/.my.cnf`:

```
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = <usuario>
password = <contraseña>
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Te dará flexibilidad a la hora de no tener que estar agregando todos esos parámetros en cada llamada a `mysql`.

Gracias a esto último tu línea podría resumirse en:

```
mysql -e \
  "INSERT INTO tabla
    (nombre, tipo, fecha, estacion)
  VALUES
  (
    '${archivoF//\'/\'},${archivoG//\'/\'}',
    '${tipoOb//\'/\'},${tipoNa//\'/\'}',
    '${fcha//\'/\'}', '${st//\'/\'}'
  )" base_de_datos
```

`Bash` no dispone de ninguna función especial para escapar los caracteres especiales de una consulta SQL, así que he usado el modificador de sustitución de todas las coincidencias (Pattern substitution, `//`) que sustituirá todas las comillas simples (`'`) en una comilla simple escapada (`\'`). No es muy habitual que el nombre de un archivo tenga una comilla, pero tendrás que tener en cuenta ese detalle.